# count and group values in column with condition in R

Tags: r, countif

I would find a fast way to get a count of values in specific column that match some conditions and then produce a summary table for each condition.

Specifically, let's say this is my df:

```
df <- data.frame(X = sample(1:100))
```

To know how many observations are less than 25, between 25 and 50 and greater than 50 I simply use count function:

```
count(df, df$X <25)
count(df, df$X >=25 & df$X <=50)
count(df, df$X > 50)
```

I was just wondering, if there is a way to get the same results in a more efficient way, and maybe in table format, something like this:

```
<25     24
25-50   26
>50     50
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Use `cut` with `table` i.e. `with(df, table(cut(X, breaks = c(-Inf, 25, 51, Inf), include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE, labels = c("<25", "25-50", ">50")))))`

Comment: Do you really have integers?

Comment: In this case yes